# Issue with BaseAdapter getView(int position) with listviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I wrote some adapters for listviews. I need to draw some elements of those views with different layouts based on a property.

So I pass two ArrayList data and ArrayList property to the adapter and in getView(int position) I check property.get(position)

The problem is that position doesn't seem to be related to the entire list but only on part of it which changes depending on the current view (for instance: scrolling it)

How can I get the desired effect?
and why the issue doesn't affect the data arraylist?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    /**
     * Holder mantiene una reference all'albero delle views per evitare chiamate continue di findiViewById
     */
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null){

        /** si usa inflate solo se è null */
         holder = new ViewHolder();



         if (!lemon.get(position)){
             view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, null);
             holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
         }else {
             view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_lemon_layout, null);
             holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
         }

         view.setTag(holder);


    }else {


        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    holder.name.setText(names.get(position));

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount`:

```
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return lemon.get(position)?0:1;
        }
```

Your code should now work in `getView`.

Comment: thanks, how do I set the viewtypes? .just to know is there a way to do the same in getView?

Comment: That is it. You should probably use a static int TYPE_LEMON = 0 and a static int TYPE_NOT_LEMON = 1 instead of 0 and 1. In your getView just check the type using getItemViewType(position) to choose what to inflate and how to prepare your view. But anyway if you only add these two functions, your code should work perfectly.